# Grouping two columns (using comma is not working as desired)

Tags: mysql, group-by

How can I group two columns?

My current query:

```
SELECT 
MIN(DATE_FORMAT(t.date_booked, '%Y-%m-%d')) as date,
MIN(DATE_FORMAT(i.inv_date, '%Y-%m-%d')) as invdate,

FROM Hours as t

LEFT JOIN Proj as p
ON t.pid = p.id

LEFT JOIN inv_c as c
ON t.pid = c.pid

LEFT JOIN inv as i
ON c.pid = i.id


WHERE t.pid = "2005"


GROUP BY MONTH(t.date_booked), MONTH(i.inv_date)
ORDER BY t.date_booked, i.inv_date ASC
```

The output of this is

```
|       date        |       invdate     |
|   2015-01-02      |       2015-02-10  |
|   2015-01-02      |       2015-02-15  |   
|   2015-01-05      |       2015-02-10  |
|   2015-01-05      |       2015-02-15  |   
.....
```

Is that what its supposed to do? Because it looks like its only grouping the invdate column,

I also tried adding 'AND' on the group by clause `GROUP BY MONTH(t.date_booked) AND MONTH(i.inv_date)`

But it only outputted the first row

```
|       date        |       invdate     |
|   2015-01-02      |       2015-02-10  |
```

My desired output is like this:

```
|       date        |       invdate     |
|   2015-01-02      |       2015-02-10  |
|   2015-01-05      |       2015-02-15  |
```

What's the best way to get that working?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using only GROUP BY t.date_booked, i.inv_date instead of GROUP BY MONTH(t.date_booked), MONTH(i.inv_date)?

Comment: Whatever you do, don't give us the input because that would be way too easy.

Comment: That's why I always say that MySql way of not following the SQL ANSI pattern is horrendous because it causes people to often using GROUP BY the wrong way and having no clue what is happening...